# TextBox that Gets the value of another TextBox VISUAL C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox

Is It possible that if I create two TextBoxes.

When the first TextBox is modified from input, the second text box is set to be read only and its value will update depending on what you had written in the first text box.

It's like when I am posting here in stackoverflow there is also a read only area that follows what I'm typing (The preview window). :)) Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you've got so far?

Comment: Also, is this a web app or a windows app?

Comment: yes this is possible, but it would be nice to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, minor point, but a read-only textbox doesn't really need to be a textbox.  I'm not certain but I think a label would work just as well assuming the amount of text isn't too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's win-form application, it's so simple. try this :

```
    private void txtFirstTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstTextBox.Text)) {
            txtSecondTextBox.Clear();
            return;
        }
        txtSecondTextBox.Text = txtFirstTextBox.Text;
    }
```

hope this help.

Comment: Note that the solution that s.amani has provided here will work for both WinForms and WPF, however there are more "WPF-y" solutions to use if you are in fact working with WPF.

Comment: @kevek- Yes it's suitable for both WPF and Win-Form application. But It's better to use only in Win-Forms. WPF has excellent binding features which you've described.

Comment: Just wanted to make that clear in case it wasn't known by the OP (or anyone else looking)

Comment: If you code it like that, when you delete everything in the first textbox, the second one won't get updated. I believe that Text property is never null for a TextBox, and if it happens to be empty - why should we flee? It's a value as valid as any other.

Comment: @Morawski- Oooops, yes you right I missed clear first TextBox inside the if condition. Thanks for inform me. Take a look at update.

Answer (score 0):

**I should note: This is a solution if you're using WPF for your UI.**

Yes that's easily possible if you have, for example the first textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstBox"/>
```

You can bind to this text box's content via:

```
<TextBox x:Name"SecondBox" Text="{Binding ElementName="FirstBox", Path="Text", UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

And when the first text box changes, the second one should follow suit. This is all handled automatically for you via binding, it connects to the Text property on the TextBox named "FirstBox". This second TextBox is disabled by setting the IsEnabled property to "False"

Comment: Assuming it's WPF, not WinForms (but he didn't say)

Comment: Agreed, I edited my answer to include that disclaimer at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is already a WPF Solution and you didn't specify which you are using, I'll go ahead and post a WinForms solution.

Luckily, this is relatively simple in WinForms as well. You simply wire a TextChanged event handler for the first text box which updates the text of the second:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

Comment: I think there is no need to Cast object, when you can access by its name ? Right ?

Comment: @s.amani - If you directly access textBox1 from the event handler, then no there's no need to cast. In this case, I wrote the event handler so that it could be used for multiple text boxes getting the reference to the TextBox via the sender parameter. In that case, it certainly does need to be cast.

Comment: You mean: textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;    Yes, that will also work.